# Processing a list and creating a filter - insterting -AND inbetween content

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a list of users(.txt):

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

That I would like to use as a filter on a cmdlet (get-qaduser). I would like to ignore the users in the list.

I try

```
$filter = Get-Content users.txt | Foreach-Object { " AND Name!='{0}'" -f $_}
```

but this starts my filter with AND and I have a linebreak between each user.
How would I do this nicely?

Sune:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$filter = $filter = Get-Content users.txt | Foreach-Object { "(!samaccountname=$_)" }
$filter = "({0})" -f (-join $filter)
Get-QADUser SizeLimit 0 -LdapFilter $filter
```

The filter would look like:

```
((!samaccountname=user1)(!samaccountname=user2)...)
```

Comment: So it makes more sense to use a ldap filter than a where clause?

Comment: Yes, it filters on the server and you get back just what you asked for. With where-object the filtering is performed on the client, you get back ALL objects and only then filtering occurs. The first is much more efficient and faster

Comment: Fantastic!! Do you have a link to recommend where I can read more about Ldap-filtering?

Comment: Check these: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx